# How to restore aws httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, httpd.conf, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to aws and while trying to redirect HTTP request to https, I mistakenly overrode my httpd.conf file while following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/). my site is not working because of this. how do I restore this httpd.conf file to its default state.

I was thinking I have to get it from another ec2 instance so I set up another instance but I don't know how to access the httpd.conf file from the new instance.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

If I can get a copy of the httpd.conf file from a temporary ec2 instance, that'll help me a lot.

Comment: Did you try `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` in the new EC2 instance?

Comment: SSH to your server and replace it?! I don't understand what's preventing you from simply replacing it or fixing it. The way you edited the file in first place is the way you edit it in second place oO

Comment: i can't even ssh into the instance. i keep on getting connection timeout

Comment: Then this is not an Apache / httpd problem.

Comment: is there any other way to replace the config file apart from using ssh?

Comment: Did you try configuring your EC2 instance to allow `ssh (port 22)` from all IPs?

Comment: yes i did that using the security group attached to the instance

Comment: if anyone can ssh into an ec2 instance and send the content a sample httpd.conf i can update mine using eb extensions.

Comment: @Hindol Allowing SSH from all IP's is not good practice and if the EC2 is public facing exposes the instance to attack from outside. OP should restrict IP access to his/her IP address only to keep security at a max.

Comment: Did you read the whole thing? He needs the httpd conf from a temporary EC2 instance.

Comment: Yes pls. i need the httpd conf from a temporary EC2 instance. that'll help me alot

Answer (score 0):

So i just want to post how i solved this for anyone else who faces this problem. i ended up deleting the instance and recreating it again. that setup a new apache server and i go everything working.